# Ошибка валидатора «The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead»

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

Есть сайт на wordpress, в котором установлена контактная форма contact form 7 с модулем внутри папки recaptcha.php, где есть такой код:

```
<noscript>
  <div style="width: 302px; height: 422px;">
    <div style="width: 302px; height: 422px; position: relative;">
      <div style="width: 302px; height: 422px; position: absolute;">
        <iframe src="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 302px; height:422px; border-style: none;">
        </iframe>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 300px; height: 60px; border-style: none; bottom: 12px; left: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; right: 25px; background: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; border-radius: 3px;">
        <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;">
        </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</noscript>
```

Прогоняю сайт через [валидатор](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?acceptlanguage=&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fstringershub.com%2Fen%2Fhome%2F) и он выбивает ошибки в этом месте

> Error: The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete.
>   Use CSS instead. From line 271, column 5; to line 271, column 194
>   te;">↩
>
> Error: The scrolling attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use
>   CSS instead. From line 271, column 5; to line 271, column 194 te;">↩  ↩

Знаю, что можно заменить соответственно frameborder="0" на style="border:0;" и scrolling="no" на style="overflow:hidden;" , но как сделать так, чтобы при обновлении плагина эти изменения не слетели? Загвоздка в том, что код не расположен в какой-либо функции..

Comment: А что, "ошибка" аппетит портит и спать мешает? Было б из-за чего волноваться :) Но можно доктайп поменять.

Comment: @SeVlad типо того, seo картину портит

Comment: Никто ничего не портит. В выдачу-то загляни. Найди хоть один сайт без "ошибок"

Answer (score 1):

Уберите frameborder="0" и в style="" добавьте код: border: 0px; 
Правда, в вашем случае в style="" уже стоит: border-style: none; поэтому ничего добавлять не надо.